# c++: segmentation fault for Trie data structure

Tags: c++, c++11, trie

I am a noobie to c++ and I'm recently learning trie data structure. As I was implementing the header file for the Trie, I've encountered segmentation fault that I cannot resolve. I used the typical print out method to find the location of the error and it turns out that this line

`temp->isEmpty = true;`

is problematic and I don't know what's wrong with it. Here's my header file code, can somebody please take a look and help me out?

```
#ifndef _TRIE_HPP_
#define _TRIE_HPP_
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    Node* children[26];
    bool isEmpty;
    string val;
    Node(){
        this->isEmpty = false;
        this->val = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<26; i++){
            this->children[i] = nullptr;
            Node* temp = this->children[I];
            //temp->val = "";     //if I add this line it will also cause segmentation fault
            temp->isEmpty = true; // this line causes segmentation fault
        }
    }
    ~Node();
};
#endif

int main(){
    string input;
    Node* myTrie = new Node(); // this line causes segmentation fault
}
```

I've also tried `temp->children[i]->isEmpty = true;`
but that also throws segmentation fault

Comment: `Node* temp = this;
            temp = children[i];` What is purpose of these lines? `temp` gets `this` then immediately gets an uninitialized `children[i]`.

Comment: you forgot to define `insert` in your `Node` class, post all of your code, this one does not produce the errors you mentioned, it simply displays nothing

Comment: @Abderrahmene Rayene
Code is now updated, but the issue still remains

Answer (score 2):

The array `children` is uninitialized, so assigning one of its element to `temp` and then dereferencing `temp` means to dereference indeterminate pointer.

Instead of that, it looks like you should initialize the array to `nullptr`.

```cpp
    Node(){
        this->isEmpty = false;
        this->val = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<26; i++){
            children[i] = nullptr; // initialize array elements
        }
    }
```

Also, in the `insert` function, a line

```cpp
if (temp == nullptr) break;
```

should be inserted before the line

```cpp
if(temp->children[index]->isEmpty == false){
```

to avoid dereferencing `nullptr`.

Comment: Tried to do that but it's still throwing segmentation error, unfortunately

Comment: @ayoMax00379 The code as posted, with this change, will not throw an exception in the constructor. Your secret `insert` function however, which should be in your posted question code, probably can,  but there is no possible way we can know that.

Comment: I see, I just included it

Comment: It's still throwing segmentation fault 11 as soon as I compile and run it. Interesting enough, I tried to add `//temp->val = ""; ` before `temp->isEmpty = true;` and that causes segmentation error as well

Comment: @ayoMax00379 Do not dereference `nullptr` nor uninitialized pointer, or you will get Segmentation Fault.